# Comparing nucleophilicity of oxygen and nitrogen in acetylation of 4-aminophenol

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution

> [image]

Here, the answer has $\ce{N}$ acting as a nucleophile making the answer (C).

I thought that $\ce{O}$ would be more nucleophilic, considering the fact that $\ce{O}$ has two lone pairs, one in conjugation with the ring, the other more readily available, compared to $\ce{N}$, where its only lone pair is in conjugation with the ring.

Why is nitrogen more nucleophilic?

Comment: How good an acylating agent is acetoxyphenol?

Comment: I guess it's because of the fact that –NH2 is a better EDG than –OH, hence it would experience a lower e-density. However, I'm not sure.